# How to get Windows Explorer back after multiple change of file manager?

Tags: registry, windows-explorer

A few months ago I shifted from Windows Explorer to Explorer++ and then Cubic Explorer. This messed up my registry. And I cant get Windows Explorer back now. It works if I run from Start Menu but not when I click desktop icons like My Computer,Recycle Bin,etc. If unregister Cubic explorer from registry and try to open any desktop icons I get Error as EXPLORER.EXE "Application not found". Please I humbly request your help.
This is my first Post so sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: This belongs to http://superuser.com.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Please post this question on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here and will be closed. You should post it (or have it merged over) to SuperUser.

Comment: I flagged this for moderators to have it moved over to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by copying registry from a different windows xp to my registry.
Just from Hkey_Root_User/ Folderfto my PC registry.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly scan your computer if there is some malware messing with your system registries.
Next option is that you can restore your registries to default.
To scan for corrupted registry do the following:
1) search for command prompt and run it as administrator.
2) Now type sfc /scannow and hit enter.
It will scan for corrupted files and replaces incorrect versions and replaces with microsoft's version.

And the last option launch a system restore from the previous restore point.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway.